# Process submitted form data in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, controller

I've got a form that's submitted to a `PaymentNotificationsController` create action.

Variables come in the form > I added stars to the important variables.

```
Parameters: {**"item_number1"=>"4"**, 
**"option_name1_1"=>"Size: UK - 4, Color: Red"**, "contact_phone"=>"035-683-3582",
 "txn_id"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "payment_type"=>"instant", "last_name"=>"Bye Bye",
**"item_name1"=>"BLACK Dress"**, "receiver_email"=>"xxxx@xxxx.com", **"quantity1"=>"1",** 
"insurance_amount"=>"0.00"}
```

The variables with the stars come in the form `item_name1, item_number1, option_name1, quantity1`. If there are 2 items in the cart, there'll also be `item_name2, item_number2, option_name2, quantity2`. 
**I need a way to extract these variables from this hash and create a `PaymentNotification` with it.**

Here's the PaymentNotification create action:

```
class PaymentNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: [:create]
     def create
       PaymentNotification.create!(params: params, 
       item_number: params[:item_number], item_name: params[:item_name], quantity: params[:quantity] 
       render nothing: true
     end
end
```

Here's a github Gist if it'll give a better picture,  i tried a loop but it didn't work > https://gist.github.com/d1t/7f3a9451500579da617134468beeca96

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {"item_number1"=>"4",
"option_name1"=>"Size: UK - 4, Color: Red", "contact_phone"=>"035-683-3582",
 "txn_id"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "payment_type"=>"instant", "last_name"=>"Bye Bye",
"item_name1"=>"BLACK Dress", "receiver_email"=>"xxxx@xxxx.com", "quantity1"=>"1",·
"insurance_amount"=>"0.00"}

1.upto(Float::INFINITY).each_with_object([]) do |i, memo|
  entity = hash.select { |k, _| k =~ /\D#{i}\Z/ }
               .map { |k, v| [k[/.+(?=\d\Z|\d\d\Z)/], v] }
               .to_h
  break memo if entity.empty?
  memo << entity
end.each do |hash|
  PaymentNotification.create!(**hash)
end
```

Here we select those parameters, that end with a digit(s), convert them to hashes that are accepted by your `Model`’s constructor and then create as many notifications as there were items.

Comment: Sorry, can you please write how i can use it with the create action? The hash comes with alot more info than i need, so i only take what i need from it and i've also labelled some of the columns differently so the hash wouldn't be able to slot into my table. Plus, the notification comes from PayPal, so i don't have the params to hand if that makes sense. Its generated after each transaction

Comment: The code above should work under all the conditions you’ve described. Since it’s not a site where others write the code for you for free, it’s now up to you to adapt the code above to your particular circumstances.

Comment: I'm sorry if that seemed the wrong way, I'm new to rails thats why i was asking because i didn't understand how to adapt it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Then instead of implementing an integration with payment services, you’d better go take a course and/or read a couple of books on the subject.

Comment: Don't be a douche. You don't need to help if you don't want to. Delete your answer in that case!